# Событие дочернего блока js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.q').click(function() {
  $('.display').toggleClass('none');

  return false;
});
```

```css
.q{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
}

.w{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

.display{
  display:block;
}

.display.none{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="q">
  div q
  <div class="w">
    div w
  </div>
</div>

<div class="display">
  123
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на дочерний блок `.w` событие не проигрывалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.q').click(function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) return false;
  $('.display').toggleClass('none');
});
```

```css
.q{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
}

.w{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

.display{
  display:block;
}

.display.none{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="q">
  div q
  <div class="w">
    div w
  </div>
</div>

<div class="display">
  123
</div>
```